# Bootstrap 3 Collapse/Accordian some elements not expanding

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a website using the bootstrap framework and having some problems with the collapse component. I just switched over to Bootstrap version 3 from an older version. In the older version the collapse worked fine in all browsers. However, now after linking to the new version of bootstrap css and javascript and updating the html tags, it is not working entirely correct. In chrome, all of the collapsed blocks work except for three of them. When I click on them nothing happens. If I force these to open when the page opens (by adding the collapse.in) then they do but when i close them and then try to open them again they will not. I have 5 separate sets of accordions and in each of the three cases where they do not work it is the last one in the set. I have compared the code of these to the rest of my code as well as to the code on the bootstrap examples and I can't seem to find any syntax errors on my part. Here is some of the code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title">
  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne">
 Mid Shore Business and Technology Park
   </a>
   </h4>
</div>
 <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">

      Content

       </div>
    </div>
  </div>


      <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapsetwo">
      Dorchester Technology Park
       </a>
       </h4>
    </div>
     <div id="collapsetwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">

     Content

       </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapsesix">
  Mistletoe Farm Project
   </a>
   </h4>
    </div>
     <div id="collapsesix" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">

      Content

       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapsenine">
  Cambridge Waterfront:  SAILWINDS PARK 
   </a>
   </h4>
</div>
 <div id="collapsenine" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

On a slightly unrelated note, none of them work in IE.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: see this bootply http://bootply.com/94352 , this working fine

Comment: hmm, did you change anything?